# Non-degenerate simplexes in a Kan complex

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff

I have the following question on simplicial sets:

> a non-constant Kan complex has a non-degenerate simplex in every sufficiently large simplicial degree?

It's Exercise 8.2.3 (p. 262) of Charles Weibel's book *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*. In fact the original question is not like this, but Weibel's errata list here [http://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/602/bookerrors.pdf](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ejmr/602/bookerrors.pdf) has p.262 line -13: ‘every n’ should be ‘every sufficiently large n’. One may need to (admit and) use the fact that the standard simplices $\Delta^n\ (n>0)$ are not Kan complexes, being the first half of Exercise 8.2.3.

[image: Exercise 8.2.3]

I've no idea about how to prove it and I've not seen this kind of result in standard books on simplicial sets like in May or Goerss-Jardine. I don't really need it but it might be useful, for example, using this, one can see that a non-constant finite simplicial set could not be a Kan complex. So I will be happy to see a solution for this.

Comment: Maybe you can show that if $x$ is a nondegenerate $n$-simplex in a Kan complex and $n>0$ then $x$ is a face of some nondegenerate $(n+1)$-simplex.

Comment: @Tom Goodwillie That sounds to be a good way to prove, could you give more details? I suspect it might happen that there may be some "holes", there may be no nondegenerate simplex in certain degrees. If you have time, you can type an answer, thanks!

Comment: I thought it through in the case $n=1$ but I did not think much about the general case. Maybe I'll try later, if nobody else solves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in Tom Goodwillie's comment, I'll prove that if $f$ is a non-degenerate $n$-simplex in a Kan complex $X$ for $n>0$, then there exists a non-degenerate $(n+1)$-simplex $g$ such that $d_{n+1}g = f$.

Let $f: \Delta^n=\Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n\}}\to X$ be a non-degenerate simplex. Consider $f' = s_{n-1}d_n f: \Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n-1, n+1\}}\to X$, whose restriction to the first $n$ vertices agrees with that of $f$. These glue together to define $\bar f: \Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n\}}\cup_{\Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n-1\}}}\Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n-1, n+1\}}\to X$.
Now I claim the following:

1. $\bar f$ extends to a simplex $g: \Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n+1\}}\to X$
2. The simplex $g$ is non-degenerate.

First, assume 1. and let us prove 2. Assume the contrary and suppose $g=s_i h$ for some $h: \Delta^n\to X$.

- If $i= n$, then this implies $f=d_{n+1}s_n h= h = d_n s_n h =f'$, but this is impossible since $f$ is non-degenerate and $f'$ is degenerate.
- If $i<n$, then $f=d_{n+1} g = d_{n+1}s_i h = s_i d_n h$, so again this contradicts to the assumption that $f$ is non-degenerate.

Therefore $g$ must be non-degenerate.

Now let us prove 1. It suffices to prove that the inclusion $i: \Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n\}}\cup_{\Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n-1\}}}\Delta^{\{0, \ldots, n-1, n+1\}}\to \Delta^{n+1}$ is an anodyne extension. For any $A\subset \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$ of cardinality $a$, let $\Lambda(A)$ be the horn $\Lambda^{a+2}_0 \hookrightarrow \Delta^{a+2} = \Delta^{\{0\}\cup A\cup \{n, n+1\}}\hookrightarrow \Delta^{n+1}$. Now observe that $i$ is the composition $i_{n-1}\circ\cdots\circ i_1 \circ i_{0}$, where $i_k$ is the "horn-filling inclusion" that fills $\{\Lambda(A)\mid |A|=k\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks @Tom Goodwillie for your idea! Just one comment: the correct formula (in my opinion) should be $f' = s_{n-1}d_n f$, and in showing $i$ to be anodyne, it will be much easier by drawing commutative diagrams, and using properness and 2-out-of-3 properties.

Comment: You’re right, fixed. It took some time to understand your argument, but you mean “it’s enough to prove the map is an trivial cofibration. Cofibration because it’s an inclusion, weak equivalence because everything is weakly contractible?” (my argument is still very easy, drew a picture and only used the definition :)

Comment: I don't quite know what you are speaking but I wrote an answer below where you can see my argument (better to draw more commutative diagrams to see some identities I claimed). Hope to be useful for others.

Comment: I just meant your $C$ is equivalent to a point (which uses the fact that it is a homotopy pushout by left properness). I see you had a bit more direct way of saying it (they’re more or less the same). But I just wanted to say that (weak equivalence+monomorphism)$\Leftrightarrow$(LLP w.r.t. Kan fibrations) is in a “less trivial tier” than this exercise, so I still prefer to prove directly (and it’s intuitively pretty clear how to attach cells, writing it down is somewhat cumbersome, though).

Answer (score 0):

Here I write an answer in the form I like (which I hope to be useful for others):

[image]

It's essentially the same as Naruki Masuda's answer above, but I don't like things like $\Delta^{\{0,1,\ldots,n-1,n+1\}}$, which I would write as the image of the map $d^n: \Delta^n\to\Delta^{n+1}$.

Comment: To be honest, I see no difference except for notational preference:$\Delta^{0,…,n−1,n+1}$ is just a suggestive name for the subobject $d_n:\Delta^n→\Delta^{n+1}$ that makes simplicial identities look obvious. Diagrams are also the same as identities that we identify subconsciously, and in this proof, there is no serious diagram chase, so I didn't feel like to bother to type. The main point is to come up with an appropriate extension problem (for which drawing a picture of a simplex is useful), and the rest is straightforward. But If you feel happier with this, I'm happy as well.